# how to install package with pypi in python 2.7?

Tags: python, pypi

this problem, I have when try install package netstat with pypi

```
[opmeitle@localhost ~]$ sudo pip install netstat
[sudo] password for opmeitle: 

Downloading/unpacking netstat
  Running setup.py egg_info for package netstat

    file nester_g:.py (for module nester_g:) not found
Installing collected packages: netstat
  Running setup.py install for netstat
    file nester_g:.py (for module nester_g:) not found
    file nester_g:.py (for module nester_g:) not found
    warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install


    file nester_g:.py (for module nester_g:) not found
    file nester_g:.py (for module nester_g:) not found
Successfully installed netstat
Cleaning up...
```

and other question: how to install packages in python2.7 and not in 3?

Answer (score 3):

While [Kugel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13319820/1497947) is perfectly valid, I would also urge you to avoid system wide install, and to use a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).
It will allow you to create a sandbox for your project and isolate it from others.

When creating a virtualenv, you can specify the Python interpreter version you want to use. For example, for python2.7:

```
$ virtualenv path/to/project -p /usr/bin/python2.7
```

Then, a `pip install` command will automatically install the package for python2.7.

Answer (score 2):

1. The package you mention is corrupted / incomplete. Download source code from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/netstat/1.3.0) and you can see there is only setup.py and no other source code. Beside that, the homepage is a broken link.
2. To install for a different version of python use `pip-2.7 install xxx`. There is usually a pip-x.y for each python version you have installed.